# How to view file diff in git before commit

Tags: git, git-diff

This often happens to me:

I'm working on a couple related changes at the same time over the course of a day or two, and when it's time to commit, I end up forgetting what changed in a specific file. (This is just a personal git repo, so I'm ok with having more than one update in a commit.)

Is there any way to preview the changes between my local file, which is about to be checked in, and the last commit for that file?

Something like:

```
git diff --changed /myfile.txt
```

And it would print out something like:

```
line 23
  (last commit): var = 2+2
  (current):     var = myfunction() + 2

line 149
  (last commit): return var
  (current):     return var / 7
```

This way, I could quickly see what I had done in that file since it was last checked in.

Answer (score 952, accepted):

If you want to see what you haven't `git add`ed yet:

```
git diff myfile.txt
```

or if you want to see already added changes

```
git diff --cached myfile.txt
```

Comment: check out `git add -p`. Review every change, selectively approve changes to stage, abort at any time if you change your mind, and even inline edit a chunk. I never `git add` without it.

Comment: how can you exit the file?

Comment: @Kick Try pressing `q`

Comment: also, if you want to remove the silly 'a/' and 'b/' prefixes in diff result, you can set `git config --global diff.noprefix true`.

Comment: great, this also works without file parameter. I use this when I checked out another file in my current branch. thanks

Answer (score 79):

```
git diff HEAD file
```

will show you changes you added to your worktree from the last commit. All the changes (staged or not staged) will be shown.

Comment: Your solution works. But I am a bit confused. HEAD points to the latest commit number. So, when we git add, the index of working directory is updated and not the HEAD. So how does it shows the difference.

Answer (score 22):

To check for local differences:

```
git diff myfile.txt
```

or you can use a diff tool (in case you'd like to revert some changes):

```
git difftool myfile.txt
```

<sup>To use `git difftool` more efficiently, install and use your favourite GUI tool such as Meld, DiffMerge or OpenDiff.</sup>

Note: You can also use `.` (instead of filename) to see current dir changes.

In order to check changes per each line, use: `git blame` which will display which line was commited in which commit.

---

To view the actual file before the commit (where `master` is your branch), run:

```
git show master:path/my_file
```

Answer (score 22):

Another technique to consider if you want to compare a file to the last commit which is more pedantic:

```
git diff master myfile.txt
```

The advantage with this technique is you can also compare to the penultimate commit with:

```
git diff master^ myfile.txt
```

and the one before that:

```
git diff master^^ myfile.txt
```

Also you can substitute '~' for the caret '^' character and 'you branch name' for 'master' if you are not on the master branch.

Answer (score 16):

Did you try `-v` (or `--verbose`) option for `git commit`? It adds the diff of the commit in the message editor.

Comment: Good answer. This can provide information in commit editor , makes me commit more easily. Is there any way to close the information area of `Changes not staged for commit:` which can make commit editor more clean.

Comment: Didn't work for me. "Diff Editor" simply was not shown and committed without asking.... TortoiseGit is much better.

Answer (score 15):

I think this is the perfect use case warranting a GUI. - Although I totally understand that it can also be achieved well enough within the command line.

Personally, every commit of mine, I do from the git-gui. In which I can make multiple atomic commits with separate hunks/lines if it makes sense to do so.

Gut Gui enables viewing of the diffs in a well formatted colored interface, is rather light. Looks like this is something you should checkout too.

Comment: I agree - it also allows you to edit the commit message while looking at the diff.

Comment: Good to know, but I'd like to stick to CLI. I've used a couple packages that had it, but I've moved to strictly terminal / vim for my workflow. Thanks though.

Comment: Yeah if you stick to the GUI there are a lot of cool features like `git bisect` that aren't really accessible.

Comment: I agree - There are many options for which it is much faster and makes more sense to use command line. However, previewing changes isn't one of them.

Comment: There are also text user interfaces, that run in terminal. One worth checking out is `tig` "text-mode interface for Git".

Answer (score 15):

On macOS, go to the git root directory and enter `git diff *`

Comment: easily my favorite answer!(and works on linux as well) I was wanting a way to do this so that I can make a good sumary for my git commit comment incase I forgot some of the things I did.

Answer (score 6):

The best way I found, aside of using a dedicated commit GUI, is to use `git difftool -d` - This opens your diff tool in directory comparison mode, comparing HEAD with current dirty folder.

Answer (score 4):

```
git difftool -d HEAD filename.txt
```

This shows a comparison using VI slit window in the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

The diff can be done with `git diff` (followed by the filename or nothing if you want to see the diff of all modified files).
But if you already did something like `git add *`, you have to undo with `git restore --staged .` first.

Answer (score 0):

### BEFORE COMMIT

to be sure what is about to be committed:

```
git diff --cached
```

### Any changes including not committing (not staged)

```
git diff
```

- use arrow key to scroll down.
- press `Q` to exit diff